# Как правильно объявить структуру, которая будет использоваться в классе?

Tags: c++

Как правильно объявить структуру, которая будет использоваться в классе?
Все в одном .h файле так:

```
struct Tdata{
    std::string name;
    std::string second_name;
    //....
};

class A{
    private:
         Tdata data;
         //...
};
```

или так:

```
class A{
    private:
         struct Tdata{
            std::string name;
            std::string second_name;
            //....
        } data;
         //...
};
```

или вообще разнести обявление структуры и класса по разным файлам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если структура используется только внутри класса и тем более как private член, то конечно лучше ее объявление инкапсулировать в определение класса.

Если же вы хотите использовать структуру помимо определения класса, то лучше ее объявить отдельно от класса.

Обратите внимание, что внутри класса само объявление структуры может иметь класс доступа public, тогда как член данных класса с этим типом может иметь класс доступа private.

```
class A{
    public:
         struct Tdata{
            std::string name;
            std::string second_name;
            //....
        };
    private:
        Tdata data;
         //...
};
```

Все зависит от того, как вы собираетесь использовать класс и структуру, какой  интерфейс вы хотите предоставить пользователям класса и структуры.

Кроме того в случае если само определение вложенной структуры не используется в классе, то структуру можно определить вне класса, а в самом классе только объявить ее. Например

```
class A{
    public:
        struct TData;
    private:
        Tdata *data;
         //...
};

struct A::Tdata{
    std::string name;
    std::string second_name;
    //....
};
```

Comment: Нарвался на интересный глюк, если объявлять указатель на структуру внутри класса (Tdata *data;), то программа вылетает с ошибкой, причем только код компилятора MinGW. Второй компилятор (Cygwin) создает вполне рабочую программу

Comment: @xttz  Чтобы что-то сказать по этому поводу, нужно хотя бы знать сообщение об ошибке, выдаваемое компилятором.

Comment: Компилятор без ошибок и предупреждений работает, вылетает уже само приложение после запуска "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.918 s" среда CodeBlocks

Comment: @xttz Я думаю, это связано с какой-нибудь ошибкой в вашей программе, и она имеет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Да там и нет ничего еще в этой программе, только начал все в кучу собирать, https://cloud.mail.ru/public/M2Bu/cooqdJ5VX и сразу нарвался

Answer (score 0):

Использовал вот такой способ:

```
class Core
{
    public:
        Core();
        virtual ~Core();
        struct InData;
    protected:
    private:
        InData *stData;
};

struct Core::InData {
        int a;
        int b;
};
```

после того как в одном из методов класса использую

```
stData->a = 5;
```

программа вылетает с ошибкой после запуска

Comment: я правильно понимаю что мне нужно добавить в конструктор класса это: stData = new InData;

Comment: Причина скорей всего в том, что вы не инициализировали указатель stData. Он должен указывать на реально сщуствующий объект. Например, в конструкторе вы могли бы добаваить предложение stData = new inData();

Comment: Просто удивительно, что компилятор из cygwin работает и его это не заботит, у него даже без инициализации указатель ссылается на какой-то адрес памяти, а не NULL.

Comment: Если указатель не был инициализирован, то он может содержать любое случайное значение. В этом случае поведение программы неопределенное.